# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot recognize input near 'num' ':' '=' in expression specification;

Tags: mysql, json, apache-spark-sql

Sorry the title is a bit long but it is accurate:

I have a mysql table **products (select product_id, product_category_id, product_price)** to be query to get the top 3 records from each category and my query is working, I need to do the same thing through Spark in the registered temp table:

```
val query = """
select product_id, product_category_id, product_price
from 
(
   select product_id, product_category_id, product_price,
      (@num:=if(@group = product_category_id, @num +1, if(@group := product_category_id, 1, 1))) row_number 
  from products t
  CROSS JOIN (select @num:=0, @group:=null) c
  order by product_category_id, product_price desc, product_id
) as x 
where x.row_number <= 3
"""
```

if the query is parsable, I can get the same result with:
`val result = sqlContext.sql(query)`

However, I received the error mentioned in the title:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot recognize input near
>   'num' ':' '=' in expression specification; line 5 pos 11

Can I make that conclusion that there is some limitation on grammar between SparkSQL and MySQL? or am I missing anything here? Do you have a different way to get the top 3 records from each group in MySQL?

Thank you.

If you have a solution and want to try it out on the table, you can find the json data here: 
https://github.com/mdivk/175Scala/blob/master/data/product.json

Comment: Hello Choix, I dont know if Spark SQL is compatible with MySQL I just know that it should be compatible with HiveQL thus you can open a Hive client and make your tests there

Comment: Tahnk you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who read this in the future:

I believe this is because `@num:=` is not supported in SparkSQL, what I end up with is a new query below using the partition and row_number:

```
val query = """
select  product_id , product_category_id, product_price,  row_number() over(partition by product_category_id  order by product_price  desc) as p_order from products  """
```

This is accepted in SparkSQL and returns what I was expecting.

Thanks.